# How to order using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

```
/(summer camp)|(summer)|(camp)/
Forest camp
summer ramadan
summer camp
summer rakatun
```

I have test data on the link "summer camp", "summer", "camp", me need to make a regular expression so that "summer camp" becomes the first match

regexp has a search order of matches, I need the first match to find a summer camp, despite the fact that it is third on the list. But now the first "camp" match.

https://regex101.com/r/YWgrlO/1/

Comment: Code must be put into your question

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regexp has a search order of matches, I need the first match to find a summer camp, despite the fact that it is third on the list. But now the first "camp" match.`

Not sure what you mean but if you want to find these in a prioritized
sequence that finds *summer camp* first, it'd be something like this

`(?s)(summer camp)(?:.+?(summer|camp)?)?`

https://regex101.com/r/0A7TBD/1